# pandasのヘッダが数字になってしまったときの対処法

Tags: python, pandas

`cross = pd.crosstab(x["id"], x["flag"])`
として以下のデータフレームが生成されました。
「9」列が0でないものに絞りたいのですが、

```
cross
Out[1]:
flag      1  2  3  4  5  9
id
10001    1  0  1  0  2  0
10002    1  0  0  0  1  0
10003    1  0  0  0  1  0
10004    1  0  0  0  1  0
10005    1  0  0  0  1  0
cross[cross.9 >= 1]
  File "<ipython-input-132-22b4f5ce4612>", line 1
    cross[cross.9 >= 1]
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

とりあえず9列だけ出力しようとしてもうまく行かず、
renameもうまくいきませんでした。

```
cross['9']
KeyError: '9'


cross.9
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

この後の操作や、データの作り等からilocなどで列番号での指定は避けたいです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

**実行環境**
Windows 10
Python 3.7

Comment: flag列を予め1→flag1、2→flag2のように変換するという手を思いつきましたがあまりスマートではないですね。。

Comment: `cross.columns = cross.columns.map(str)` として文字列型に変換するという方法が考えられます。そうすれば `cross['9']` でアクセス可能かと。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

columnsの属性について見てみました。

```
cross.columns
Out[11]: Int64Index([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9], dtype='int64', name='flag')
cross.columns.map(str)
Out[12]: Index(['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '9'], dtype='object', name='flag')
```

Int64Indexという属性になるとアクセスが困難になるようです。

metropolilsさんに頂いた回答の通り、`cross.columns = cross.columns.map(str)`とすれば`cross['9']`でアクセスもでき、renameも可能でした。
ありがとうございました。